# I want to use a variable which contains a cell reference within a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying this code out and If I use direct cell reference in the formula it works fine but when I substitute the cell reference for a variable it doesn't work.
Can you tell me where im going wrong. 
The aim is to add up all the cells which contain a date in november

This is the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim last As Long
    Dim cussat As Variant
    Dim Cussatrange As String

    With ActiveSheet
        last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    If Target.Address = "$C$" & last + 1 Then
        Range("$B$" & last + 1).Value = Date
        Range("$A$" & last + 1).Value = "Moss"
        Cussatrange = "J1:J" & last

        ' I would like to substitue the cell reference in the above formula to use Cussatrange or last 
        cussat = [=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(J1:J43,"mmm yyyy")="Nov 2014"))]

        MsgBox "Last used row number in column A is " & last & "  " & cussat & "  " & Cussatrange

    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can use something like this:

```
Dim myFormula As String
Dim template As String

template = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT({0},""mmm yyyy"")=""Nov 2014""))"
myFormula = Replace(template, "{0}", Cussatrange)

cussat = Application.Evaluate(myFormula)

MsgBox "Last used row number in column A is " & last & "  " & cussat & "  " & Cussatrange
```

- In the code a template for the formula is created and then the substring (in this case it is {0}) is repalaced with the address which is stored in the string Cussatrange.
- For more info about Application.Evaluate method have a look here: 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019%28v=office.15%29.aspx. 
  *(Using square brackets (for example, "[A1:C5]") is identical to calling
  the Evaluate method with a string argument)*

Comment: Dee   I don't understand your answer or how it works but it works fine. I now have to do the same for 3 other columns to count the same month.  Thanks ever so much.